# Can fiddler to show Internet Explorer XHR traffic

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

Trying to debug some ajax calls not working properly in IE, i noticed that XHR traffic shows up in fiddler when i use Chrome or Firefox, but not for IE. But the traffic does occur, since i see it in the server logs. Thought it might be just my machine, but i've reproduced this IE8 and IE9 on Win7 and Win2k8 Server.

Is there a setting in IE or fiddler to capture this traffic?

Comment: It's always worked fine for me, is Tools > Options > Connections [Monitor All Connections] ticked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It absolutely works in IE.  In fact, IE and Chrome will use the same proxy settings, so if it is working in Chrome, it should work in IE.

You might have some other settings (such as another proxy) getting in the way.  Additionally, some malware might be taking over the proxy setting.

Comment: Turns out one of my machines did have the IE proxy setting set up wrong and the other had just been aggressively caching the XHR requests, so i never saw them on the wire. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for setting up fiddler with IE.

http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Typically IE traffic should automatically by captured in the fiddler, but if you have some non-default settings, the hookup guide might help you.