# Access Denied with $http request in Angular and IE8

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I am trying to get my angular app to do an $http.get request. Works everywhere but IE8. I am using latest Angular (1.0.6 I think).  The only message IE gives is:TypeError:

Access is denied.
   undefined (in previous angular this was )

My host (nodejs)is set to send cors headers:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); //config.allowedDomains
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Requested-By');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

I have tried to get more info about the error using debug tools but:

Fiddler: doesn't show xmlhttprequests - seems you can hack your NET app to fix that but not sure what to do with my web page.
DebugBar: doesn't show these requests either
FirebugLite: 2 version I tried are broken - just random errors and doesn't load

Changing the hosts to same origin clears the issue so I assume it's trying something but man it's hard to debug.

Angular posts on this seem outdated and I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Fiddler totally does show XHR for IE. If it didn't, that would be a HUGE oversight. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351238/can-fiddler-to-show-internet-explorer-xhr-traffic

Comment: Also to be accurate, IE8 and IE9 don't have XHR, but instead do XDomainRequest, or XDR.

Comment: Well I have read that fiddler post and check setting and for the life of me I cannot see any of these requests. Other posts indicate a proxy has to be set for fiddler to pick these up. And I am aware of the IE8 XHR - XDomainRequest - I just can't seem to fund current Angular docs on this. Some older posts indicate there is no support for XDomainRequests but not sure what current status is - I find it hard to believe that IE8 will not work with Angular $http

Comment: it's very possible that my setup is what is making Fiddler not work - vmware client to an OSX Nodejs server. Nevertheless the main issue is simply getting IE8 to work

Comment: Thats how my system is setup (granted I dont test IE8). I do know that $http should work with IE8, so there is likely some other issue.

Comment: Have you set withCredentials ?  see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598917/adding-a-custom-header-to-http-request-using-angular-js

Comment: @KevinHakanson not the issue - I don't use Auth - tried it just in case though

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with $http. $http lets you make XHR(XDR) or JSONP requests. It doesn't provide a mechanism to circumvent the browsers same origin policy.

> Changing the hosts to same origin clears the issue so I assume it's trying something but man it's hard to debug.

That's the key to your problem. IE8 doesn't support Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (CORS) very well. In order to make cross domain calls with IE8, you better off either:

1. Use your nodejs app to proxy the request for you, letting you use the same domain.
2. Use JSONP in your $http.get() request

There are a number of gotchas associated with CORS and IE8, which are [outlined here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).

Comment: Seems like I could use XDomainRequest - someone made a fork of angular with support for this but it's outdated now.

Comment: I would recommend against using XDomainRequest. The Angular folks had a good reason why they didn't merge this feature in, it's not a great solution.

If possible in your case, I would just proxy the request either using nodejs or by adding apache with mod_proxy in front of the node app.

Comment: OlliM is right, XDR sucks. By default, expressjs's form parser can't parse data that is posted, because XDR only supports text/plain content-types. No custom header support, no preflight requests, etc.

Comment: Angular 1.2 doesn't support IE<=9 CROS.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this same issue, and while it's likely not ideal, one solution is to change IE's 'Access data sources across domains' security setting to *Enable* or *Prompt*:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346862.aspx

In my case I was running into the same thing when trying to fetch data (via angular's $resource) from my own API that was hosted on another domain. In IE8 & IE9 these requests would fail with the error you described above. Changing the security setting in IE to allow cross-domain data requests resolved that problem.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS doesn't support IE<=9 CORS.

As required, there is a link to github official AngualrJS website :

[AngularJS Github official discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11355)

Comment: Why -1 please say it?

Comment: Please provide a link supporting your claim. Then I'll remove my -1